# How to add a number to start and stop of a slice object in Python?

Tags: python, slice

I read [this question about slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/6256241) to understand the slicing in Python a bit better, but found nothing about increasing the `start` and `stop` of a slice object by a constant in a simple way. By "simple" I mean: a) in *the same line* and b) in *one place* and c) *without* an extra variable.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][0:2]         #works
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][(0:2)+1]     #does not work, what I would find most convenient
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][(0+1):(2+1)] #works, but needs a change at two places
i = 1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][(0+i):(2+i)] #works but needs an extra line and variable
```

On the slice level, `slice(0, 2, 1)+1` does not work since `"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'slice' and 'int'"`. So, how to add a number to start and stop arguments of a slice object in Python in a simple way?

Comment: it looks like your final example does what you want, can you clarify your question

Comment: How you solve this problem depends on what the surrounding code does and looks like. Using a variable seems a good enough solution.

Comment: @Qaswed Are you trying to ask how to get a fixed sized slice but be able to easily change where you are taking the slice from? Like you might want `arr[0:2]` or `arr[2:4]` or `arr[4:6]`.

Comment: @depperm I made clear what "simple" means to me, and thus why my final example is not "simple" in my sense and is not the desired solution for me.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid writing `+i` twice you could do something like

```
my_list[i:][:length]
```

Example:

```
i = 2
length = 3
print(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'][i:][:length])

--> output: ['2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example @Heike +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve such a thing. If you really want to do that with only one line, you still can do:

```
x=1; l[x:x+2]
```

But this is a little ugly...